# Error shown each time open mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Each time I open my terminal(mac laptop). I get this weird looking error which never goes away. Almost a year now. Please what does it mean?

```
-bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'


-bash: command substitution: line 1: `/usr/libexec/java_home -v <version>'
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sXcY.png
Although the terminal still works but I don't know what these two lines mean.

Comment: check your `.bashrc` or `.profile`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please what do you mean by i should check them? Any leads with regards to where I can find them? And when I do, what am I to look for? Thank you.

Comment: cd into `~` you should find the `.bashrc` there